# Преобразовать массив в число

Tags: java, массивы

Суть вопроса в том как из массива

```
int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

получить число 12345 ?
P.S Прошу сильно не пинать, новичок.

Comment: Идеи у вас есть какие-нибудь?

Comment: @a_gura Умножить на 10000 + 1000+...+10, получить число, но это по моему самый глупый способ, думал есть функция, гуглил не нашел

Comment: @gold так и написали бы в вопросе свое решение и попросили бы лучшие варианты. А то выглядит как просьба решить проблему за вас.

Comment: @a_gura Не хотел выглядеть глупо )

Comment: @gold А все равно получилось ;)

Comment: @a_gura Главное понять что и как, дальше больше :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну если в лоб

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [] arr = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int result = 0;

    for (int i =arr.length -1 , n = 0; i >= 0; --i, n++) {
        int pos = (int)Math.pow(10, i);
        result += arr[n] * pos;
    }
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Comment: Вот примерно так и думал ) Интересно есть ли еще какие варианты ?

Comment: можно без степени, а с делителем на 10...но суть в том, что все ровно придется, подставлять числа разряды...
А к вечеру, да голова не варит)

Comment: Вариантов, конечно, не один и все приведут к правильному решению. Запили хоть какой-нибудь и радуйся... или ты собираешь решения?

Comment: @Stas0n да, главное результат ) Интересно какие еще есть методы, полезно будет не только мне, все кто гуглит и попадет сюда )

Comment: Поразительно, что никто до сих пор не написал стандартный код.

Обычно он для строк, соответственно код цифры переводится в ее значение, делается проверка, что это цифра, учитываются знак и переполнение, в случае ошибки вызывающей функции как-то о ней сообщается, но суть вот:

    long result = 0, 
         base = 10;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
       result = result * base + arr[i];
    return result;

это (base = 10) для десятичных цифр в массиве.

Answer (score 1):

Проще всего с помощью схемы Горнера:

```
public class ArrayToInt {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        int n = 0;
        for (int d : arr) {
            n = 10 * n + d;
        }
        System.out.println(n);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Уже поздно и голова особо не варит..  
Первое, что приходит на ум это склеить все в строку, а потом преобразовать как надо.
Это самый такой, топорный метод, который наверняка сработает)

Comment: @Stas0n суть задачи изначально стояла "Сложить две строки 1111(String) + 2222(String)" образно говоря, так как Interger.parseInt(); не устроил в связи с тем что int не хватит на большие значения, сделал toCharArray() перевел getNumericValue() теперь пытаюсь получить число из массива ) не полностью уверен что делаю правильно )

Comment: @gold для больших числе используйте BigInteger (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html )

Comment: Если не устраивает int, есть и другие "целые" типа. Взять хотя бы long.     
Что касается способа, то, если он будет выдавать правильны ответ, то, считай, что правильный)

Comment: @a_gura, только хотел добавить коммент про BigInteger..

Comment: @a_gura,@Stat0n Даже не знал про BigInteger обязательно гляну

Comment: BigInteger - штука хорошая, но под задачи, как и BigDecimal, это хорошо с DB юзать, а если задачи простые и точности простых типов хватает, то мало смысла...

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Test_ArrayToInt {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,100};
        String str = "";
        BigInteger _a = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            str += a[i];
        }
        _a = new BigInteger(str);
        System.out.println(_a);
    }
}
```

Можно попробовать вот так.

Comment: Это совсем не то, что спрашивает ТС.

Comment: @avp @snurmax его ответ тоже был полезен, BigInteger заюзал, сложил два 85-значных числа ) Задание выполнено.

Answer (score 0):

```
int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,100};
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
for(int i=0; i < a.length; i++)
   sb.append(a[i]);
return Long.parseLong(sb.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Домножаем каждое число на 10 в соответствующей степени и суммируем результат:

```java
int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

// домножаем каждое число на 10
// в соответствующей степени и суммируем
int sum = IntStream.range(0, arr.length)
        .map(i -> (int) (Math.pow(10, arr.length - 1 - i) * arr[i]))
        .sum();

System.out.println(sum == 12345); // true
```

---

Получаем из каждого числа строку, соединяем строки и преобразовываем в число:

```java
int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

// получаем из каждого числа
// строку и соединяем строки
String str = Arrays.stream(arr)
        .mapToObj(String::valueOf)
        .collect(Collectors.joining());

// преобразовываем строку в число
int num = Integer.parseInt(str);

System.out.println(num == 12345); // true
```